# Pass jquery string to Code Behind file ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a string generated from jquery e.g *string1,string2,string3,stringn* . I need to submit this data using jquery to the another asp page which will process the string. How can I get this string to the C# code? I would like to use code behind file to process this comma separated list. 
Very new in ASP.NET\C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to post the JSON to the server:
For this you can have the opportunity to send via $.ajax() or you can access a PageMethod like this: (this one is also a javascript code on the given page)

```
 //obj is the object what you have on the clientside. (f.e. an array of strings)
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj, '');

 //in this example the method's name is LoadItems and the IfSuccess 
 //and IfError methods for callbacks
 PageMethods.LoadItems(jsonString, this.IfSuccess, this.IfError, this);
```

After this on the server side, you need to deserialize the json into an a specified class, object[] or a string[] if you have only strings. Here is an example for your case:

```
            [WebMethod]
            public static string LoadStrings(string jsonString)
            {
                try
                {
                    JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                    string[] stringArray = s.Deserialize<string[]>(jsonString);
                }
                ...
            }
```

Whit this solution you can access your strings in the stringArray.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an AJAX request to your asp.net application. jQuery has a $.ajax() method to help make this easier for you.

You could also use a traditional 'form' and just have jquery stick the data in a hidden field and trigger the submit.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the jquery post method as follows:

```
$.post('File Address', {data : your String});
```

Then retrieve it in the asp.net page.